# How to throw KeyError instead of returning NaN with a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering if there is a way to index a DataFrame with a list of values
such that when a key is not present a `KeyError` is thrown instead of returning
`NaN`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,6],[2,7]], index=['A', 'B'], columns=['type1', 'type2'])
```

For indexing a single value this works as desired

```
df.loc["A", ["type3"]]
...
KeyError: 'the label [type3] is not in the [index]'
```

but with multiple keys it returns `NaN`

```
df.loc["A", ["type2", "type3"]]
type2    6.0
type3    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

There are some obvious hacks such as looping through the list, but I'm
wondering if there is any cleaner/ more efficient solution?

Answer (score 1):

without .loc missing column names does result in error. So, just chain:

```
df[["type2", "type3"]].loc["A",:]
```

I always liked feature of 'NaN' return. Came in handy each time i wanted to make test data compatible with train data. However, now in pandas 1.0 even with .loc missing column names results in an exception

Comment: Please re-format your answer - also: ```df[["type2", "type3"]].loc["A"]```

Comment: i didnt get what you meant by re-format your answer

Comment: Code formatting, and put some words of explanation there - I do think that your answer is absolutely correct